# How do I add a jQuery script to WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use the following script in wordpress without success. Please help me how to adapt it to Warpeders and where should I put it to make it work.

```
$(‘table tr:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+7’).addClass(‘active’);
$(‘#dates-load’).on(‘click’, function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $rows = $(‘.dates-prices-table tr’);
var lastActiveIndex = $rows.filter(‘.active:last’).index();
$rows.filter(‘:lt(‘ + (lastActiveIndex + 5) + ‘)’).addClass(‘active’);
});
```

Comment: For which page do you want to add? please add more details.

Comment: A page that has a table with a load more button, which is the script that activates the button

Comment: You need to enqueue the JS file for that page in functions.php.

Comment: So that's what I asked, how should I do it?
Copy and paste as it is, or should it be done differently format?

Comment: Also don't use this ‘ for jQuery, use either single quote ' or double quotes ", maybe that's the reason it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include jQuery in your Wordpress theme you have to enqueue the scripts. This is done in the functions.php file within your theme folder. Here is an example:

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0',true); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

Note that the third parameter of the wp_register_script should be the location of your jquery script, you can enter the jquery cdn here if you intend on using that instead.

Hope this helps.

Edit: I read your question wrong. What I wrote above is to include the jQuery library in your project. If you want to actually include a custom js file with jQuery code the actions are pretty much the same. Only change the third parameter of the wp_register_script to the location of your custom js file :)

Comment: Can you tell me how I should embed the code I sent in functions.php for it to work? The full version that should be so I can copy and paste there.

Comment: You should not put your jquery code in the functions.php file. Make a separate folder called js(or anything really) inside of your theme folder. Then make a file in this folder called main.js(or anything you want.js). Then put your jQuery code in this file, and then in your functions.php file use the exact code I sent in my original reply, but copy and paste the wp_register_script & wp_enqueue_script, and enqueue your custom js file as well. Now the file will be put in the header of all your wordpress pages, and then you'll be able to use jquery wherever you want.